# When passing Strings via intent only one is not null when getting the String values in the next Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing strings as intent extras, the following method is passed parameters containing the information I wish to pass via intent, I can see that the values in "mc" and "title" are as they should be in toasts:

```
 private void addProximityAlert(int id, Double latitude, Double longitude, String title, String mc) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        intent.putExtra("mc", mc);  
        intent.putExtra("gl", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);

        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Map.this, id, intent, 0);
        lm.addProximityAlert( latitude, longitude,  POINT_RADIUS,  PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,  proximityIntent  );

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"INPAMAP "+intent.getStringExtra("title")+intent.getStringExtra("mc"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }
```

Now in my next class no matter what I try and do only ever "mc" retains its value, the other variables are always null, here is the next activity:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

       Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Map.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
       Notification notification = createNotification();

       //Here I can see title is null and mc is what it should be
       Toast.makeText(context,"IN PA "+intent.getStringExtra("title")+intent.getStringExtra("mc") ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have tried using bundles and this did not work, I am completely clueless as to why only mc is being passed, when mc and title are both strings. I have tried passing only either mc or title and still only mc is not null. I tried to changing the order in which they are passed to the addproximityAlert method and also the order in which they are added as extras, I am out of options. I actually want to know how to debug properly in Eclipse so I can maybe figure out these problems myself before coming to SO, but I am under a lot of time pressure.

I would appreciate advice on how to figure out what my issue is, thank you.

Comment: try to pass `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` and `PendingIntent.getActivity`

Comment: Can you maybe show an example of how to do this, I am not sure exactly what you mean Vmironov. Thank you!

Comment: `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Map.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)` and the same thing with `PendingIntent.getActivity`

Comment: Vmironov, this fixed my issue! If you create an answer explaining how adding PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT fixed my problem I can accept it as the answer! many thanks, you saved me a whole evening of frustration! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag in `PendingIntent.getXXX` methods.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Map.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The problem is that `PendingIntent.getXXX` caches intents and can return a previously created instance without updating it. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` forces it to update the intent.
You can find more detailed explanation in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Comment: Thank you I needed to know these strings would not all pass, it was driving me crazy, thank you!!! I will study your answer!!

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against the wall on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want o figure out your problem using debugger, that's the best way to go. The way it works in eclipse is that you set up break points where you want to stop your code running and see the variables. These can be set by right clicking on the left bar beside any line number.  Now click Debug. You may do this from Project->debug. You may also right click on project and Debug -> Android Application.  Now when the app runs and reaches your break point, it shifts into debug mode. Here you can shift over break points, see variable values at each point.

In addition to this, did you try passing the whole set of values as a list? Something like: 
You could pass ArrayList from one the parent activity to the called activity. Here is a sample:

```
ArrayList<TYPE> value = new ArrayList<TYPE>();
// populate the list
value.add(CALUE);
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the target class, you may retrieve the list as follows:

```
// Call in in OnCreate()
// TYPE can be String, Double etc.
ArrayList<TYPE> list=(ArrayList<TYPE>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
```

Hope either of the two thing helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and your answer! The problem is I pass different types to the next class, int, double and string, I don't think I can store different types in an array? I will try and use debugger to see why the string is not passed with the key, because this is truly a mystery I cannot solve. Thank you!!!

Comment: I usually pass as a String array. I can then get the values in any forms. For eg: I can change from 
String to Int: 
int value = Integer.getInteger(string);
String to Double:
double d = Double.parseDouble(theString);

// If your String value cannot be parsed to double it will throw NumberFormatException.